# display an image in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net

how to browse an image location using fileupload and display it into an image control

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Asking a question without evidence of having made any effort is generally a good way to get no answers.

Comment: @user615941 - Can you expand your question a bit. Try posting some code of what you have tried and what is not working. No one here is going to write your software for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In your asp.net page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Image ID="uploadedImage" runat="server" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

And in its code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (fileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            string location = "Images/imageName.png";
            fileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + location));
            uploadedImage.ImageUrl = location;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not perfect. But it gives you a hint...